# Force MVC RouteConfig Execution?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, routes, canonical-link

In my ASP.NET MVC website, I have code in the `RouteConfig.cs` file to force the URL to include "www":

```
using Canonicalize;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MyWebsite
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Production"] == "true")
            {
                routes.Canonicalize().Www();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I host my website in Azure, which has "deployment slots." I push my code out to a "staging" slot, test, and then "swap" the "staging" slot with the "production" slot.

In the code above, you can see I'm conditionally including `routes.Canonicalize().Www();` only for the production slot. This is because the staging slot uses a URL that doesn't allow "www."

The problem is that it seems like the code in the `RouteConfig.cs` file is only fired on the initial website load. When I load the website, `RouteConfig.cs` is executed, and `routes.Canonicalize().Www();` is correctly excluded. When I swap the slots, the `RouteConfig.cs` code does not appear to be re-executed, and `routes.Canonicalize().Www();` remains excluded, which is not what I want.

Is there a way I can reliably and accurately have `routes.Canonicalize().Www();` included only for the production slot?

Comment: When you swap the slots, is your IF condition still being met, because slots can independently inject different app settings. Or does it fail to run it when you swap back and forth between the two both ways?

Comment: The "Production" setting is flagged as "deployment slot," so it stays permanently on the production slot. I.e., On the production slot, Production == true, and on the staging slot, Production = null - this remains the case even after swapping. When running the website locally with a breakpoint in RegisterRoutes.cs, when I debug, the breakpoint is actually never hit (yet I know the code is being executed), so I'm not sure why this is.

Comment: Based on the azure documentation App Settings need to be configured to 'Stick' to the deployment slot, is that something you've done? because app settings swap along with the solution. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-staging-slots

Comment: Yes, I did this (flagging as "deployment slot" = "stick"). I also manually checked the configs for both slots both before and after swapping and can confirm the setting is "sticking" with the correct slot.

Comment: Well there's nothing about your code that suggests you're doing anything wrong. I'd be curious to know if when you swap the slots if restarting the app service forces it to re-run the Register Routes method.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use application initialization module in this scenario where you can call you function to add `routes.Canonicalize().Www()`.
The application initialization module has been implemented and is available to use while you swap content between deployment slots. This module has also been implemented regarding all other operations in which a new worker is provisioned (such as auto scale, manual scale or Azure fabric maintenance). Namely, you can proactively perform initialization tasks before your app becomes available.

In order to enable the said module you need to create an applicationInitialization section where you shall define the url to be hit for the initialization task to begin. You have also the option to specify the hostName to be used for the warm up requests, something that may prove really helpful for debugging and monitoring purposes. If not otherwise specified, the “localhost” will be used as host name.

```
<system.webServer>  
  <applicationInitialization>  
    <add initializationPage="/app/initialize" hostName="warmup-requests.domain.com"/>  
  </applicationInitialization>  
<system.webServer>
```

Following the above, the swap operation between deployment slots will be completed after the code under “app/initialize” url is executed.

Reference:

https://ruslany.net/2015/09/how-to-warm-up-azure-web-app-during-deployment-slots-swap/
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/6972595-application-initialization-to-warm-up-specific-pag

Hope it helps.